# JSP components libraries like primefaces

Tags: jsp, jsf, primefaces

I there a famously used library of components such as Primefaces or Richfaces that is mainly designed to be used with JSP? And if not, then what are the possibility of using any of the aforementioned with JSP and drawbacks?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL There is really no need to be negative about it my friend. I am here to use the collective knowledge of the community and contribute to it when possible. Their experience is what I asked for. If you wish not to answer, please leave the chance to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that [ZK JSP Tags](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zkjsp) is something you look for . It is a collection of JSP Tags built upon highly interactive ZK Ajax components. It follows standard JSP specifications and integrate seamlessly with other JSP tags and solutions.

Answer (score 4):

JSP is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) since JSF 2.0 and succeeded by Facelets. You shouldn't expect JSF 2.0 component library vendors to support JSP as well, that's almost double of development and maintenance work.

So if you're looking for component libraries supporting JSP, then you should be looking at JSF 1.x targeted component libraries. RichFaces for example has the 3.3.x as the latest JSF 1.2 compatible version.

Or, just upgrade yourself first and step over to Facelets.

Comment: Well I guess then you are saying there simply is no library specifically built for JSP needs.

Comment: I didn't said that. JSF 1.x targeted component libraries support JSP. So if you need JSP, just look at JSF 1.x. But you'll miss enormous lot of advantages as offered by JSF 2.x and Facelets. JSF 1.x and JSP is really not worth the effort these days.

Comment: Aha sorry for misunderstanding. Appreciate it mate. I will review RichFaces again. Thanks,